# Why is python's subprocess.call implemented like this?

Tags: python, subprocess

The subprocess module has the convenience function `call`, which is implemented like this in both 2.6 and 3.1:

```
def call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
```

The documentation for this function carries a red warning, reading:

> **Warning**: Like `Popen.wait()`, this will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data.

The `Popen.wait()` documentation says to use `Popen.communicate()` instead in such circumstances. Well, then why isn't `call` just implemented like below instead, so the stupid warning can be removed, and silly limitations like this removed from the standard library?

```
def call(*args, **kwargs):
    input = kwargs.pop("input", None)
    p = Popen(*args, **kwargs)
    p.communicate(input)
    return p.returncode
```

I'm sure there's a reason. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spent some time looking through [PEP-324](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/), which introduced the subprocess module, trying to figure out the design decisions involved, but I think the answer is actually very simple:

There's **no reason** to pass `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` to `subprocess.call`, so the fact that it can deadlock is irrelevant.

The only reason to pass `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` to `subprocess.Popen` is so that you can use the Popen instance's `stdout` and `stderr` attributes as file objects.  Since `subprocess.call` never lets you see the Popen instance, the PIPE options become irrelevant.

There is potential overhead to `Popen.communicate` (creating additional threads to avoid deadlock by monitoring the pipes), and there's no benefit in this case, so there's no reason to use it.

**Edit**: If you want to discard your output, I guess it's better to do so explicitly:

```
# option 1
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as dev_null:
    subprocess.call(['command'], stdout=dev_null, stderr=dev_null)

# option 2
subprocess.call(['command >& /dev/null'], shell=True)
```

instead of instructing subprocess to capture all of the output to PIPE files that you never intend to use.

Comment: Controlling the output of the program is a reson to use stdout=PIPE and stderr=PIPE. That is, the python equivalent of `command >/dev/null 2>&1` and then checking `$?` in bash.

Comment: Wouldn't that be better done by `stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),  stderr=STDOUT`?

Comment: @Baffe I guess, but the point was that there _is_ a reason to use the stdout= and stderr= keyword arguments of `call`.

Comment: @lazyr - but only the PIPE variants are susceptible to deadlock.  Other uses of stdout and stderr are okay.

Comment: I think using `subprocess.call(['command >& /dev/null'], shell=True)` is the best way of doing this so far, since all the unwanted output is just discarded before reaching python... it still bothers me that it doesn't feel very pythonic though, and that it has to invoke the shell to do it. Why doesn't `call` discard all output by default if it's meant only to check the return code?

Comment: @josh Ah, that's a little tidbit I hadn't picked up. Things are starting to make some kind of sense then.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is run a command and get the exit status to determine if it succeeded or failed then you don't need to communicate with it via pipes.  That's the convenience of the subprocess.call() method.  There are other convenience functions in the subprocess module as well which encapsulate many of the common uses of using the Popen objects in an efficient manner.

If you need to pipe the child processes stdout or stderr somewhere than don't use call(), use a Popen object and communicate() with it just as the docs state.